# how to modify a function's definition graciously

Tags: emacs, lisp, elisp

Assume there is a sample function defined in a library (this question's precondition is all definitions in this library cannot be modified, something like "read only"):

```
(defun sample ()
  (foo)
  (bar)
  (baz))
```

I want to use this library, but the function `sample` cannot match my request, what I want is:

```
(defun sample ()
  (foo)
  (when condition
    (bar))
  (baz))
```

Someone told me to use `defadvice`, but I noticed that `defadvice` can only insert code before or after the invocations of `sample`, like:

```
(before-advice ...)
(sample)
(after-advice ...)
```

it cannot modify the definition of `sample` itself. So, how can I achieve this graciously? Should I have to rewrite a `sample` myself, called `my-sample` or `sample2`?

Comment: While you did give a very clear description of the problem, if you give the actual situation and function you want to override, other options might open up.

Comment: @TreyJackson The actual situation is a little complex to describe, what I wrote above is the simplest but the best description of that situation, however, now I get the answer, thanks. :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sds's answer works, except that you presumably only want to be advising `bar` when `sample` is executing, so you'd need to advise sample as well in order to activate and deactivate the advice for `bar`. My `with-temporary-advice` macro facilitates this:

```el
(defmacro with-temporary-advice (function class name &rest body)
  "Enable the specified advice, evaluate BODY, then disable the advice."
  `(unwind-protect
       (progn
         (ad-enable-advice ,function ,class ,name)
         (ad-activate ,function)
         ,@body)
     (ad-disable-advice ,function ,class ,name)
     (ad-activate ,function)))

(defadvice bar (around my-conditional-bar disable)
  ;; This advice disabled by default, and enabled dynamically.
  (when condition
    ad-do-it))

(defadvice sample (around my-sample-advice activate)
  "Make execution of `bar' conditional when running `sample'."
  (with-temporary-advice 'bar 'around 'my-conditional-bar
   ad-do-it))
```

Note that if `bar` is also called in other ways while `sample` is executing, the advice will apply for those calls as well, so you should account for that if it's a possibility.

Alternatively, you may prefer to use `flet` to redefine `bar` when required. This is subject to the same caveat as the first solution, of course.

```el
(defadvice sample (around my-sample-advice activate)
  "Make execution of `bar' conditional when running `sample'."
  (if condition
      ad-do-it
    (flet ((bar () nil))
      ad-do-it)))
```

That's *much* simpler to read, but for reasons I don't understand `flet` is, as of Emacs 24.3, no longer in favour. Its docstring suggests using `cl-flet` instead, but as `cl-flet` uses lexical binding, that won't actually work. As best I could tell, it sounded like `flet` isn't actually going away, however the current recommendation seems to be to use advice instead.

Also note that if, inside `bar`, the unwanted behaviour depended on some *variable*, then it would be preferable to use a `let` binding on that variable instead of the `flet` binding on the function.

**Edit:**

These approaches do make it harder to see what is happening, of course. Depending upon the exact situation, it may well be preferable to simply redefine the `sample` function to do what you want (or to write a `my-sample` function to call in its place, as you suggested).

Comment: A key hint to me is enough, but you gave me more than I wanted, really really thanks for your detailed answer. :-)

Comment: There is dflet, which provides flet for newer Emacs versions: https://github.com/sigma/el-x

Comment: I believe you should use `unwind-protect` in that macro.

Comment: Svante: Ah, yes indeed. Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, as you said in the "Edit" section, maybe I need to do a comparison between the complexity and my original requirement, however, your answer solves my original question.

Comment: Why do you need to repeat `bar`, `around` and `my-conditional-bar` both when defining and enabling the advice?

Comment: The advice is identified by the combination of its function, class, and name. You can't refer to a specific piece of advice without all three.

Comment: I've since learned that `(cl-letf (((symbol-function 'FOO) FUNC)) ...)` is analogous to `(flet ((FOO ...)) ...)` wrt dynamic scope for the override; so the deprecation of `flet` isn't as crazy as I'd thought at the time.

Answer (score 4):

Others have already provided good answers, but since some complain about `flet`'s disgrace, I'll show what I'd use:

```
(defvar my-inhibit-bar nil)
(defadvice bar (around my-condition activate)
  (unless my-inhibit-bar ad-do-it))
(defadvice sample (around my-condition activate)
  (let ((my-inhibit-bar (not condition)))
    ad-do-it))
```

Look ma!  No `flet` and no ugly activate/deactive!  And when you `C-h f bar` it will clearly tell you that there's more than meets the eye.  Also I'd actually use the new `advice-add` instead:

```
(defvar my-inhibit-bar nil)
(defun my-bar-advice (doit &rest args)
  (unless my-inhibit-bar (apply doit args)))
(advice-add :around 'bar #'my-bar-advice)
(defun my-sample-advice (doit &rest args)
  (let ((my-inhibit-bar (not condition)))
    (apply doit args)))
(advice-add :around 'sample #'my-sample-advice)
```

Comment: My instinct was that it's ugly to have something advised permanently if it's only needed infrequently, but greater transparency is an obvious win here, and when written in terms of this sort of 'inhibit' test, the permanence seems much more sensible. I also very much like that the new advice library is using `defun`, as we'll actually be able to use `find-function` on it! That's going to be a tremendous improvement. I do still hope `flet` *will* remain in Emacs long-term, mind, but I can see the advantages of your approach here.

Comment: I'm glad you like the new advice facility.  Hopefully `flet` will disappear at some point, tho for backward compatibility reasons you should be safe for several years.  Note that `cl-letf` is not on the way out, so while it's slightly more verbose than `flet` it's also an alternative.

Answer (score 3):

You should advise function `bar` instead, using an `around` advice:

```
(defadvice bar (around my-condition)
  (when condition
    ad-do-it))
```

Comment: Oh, thanks, my thought is so rigid that I do not realize I could advice `bar` to achieve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

I recently came across a similar problem. I need to modify `org-attach-expand` function temporarily inside `org-attach-expand-links`. Here is my solution. It seems to work and may look a bit less code than phil's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15916937/489564)

```
(defvar my-org-attach-relative-path t)

(defun my-advice-org-attach-expand (path)
  (if my-org-attach-relative-path
      (file-relative-name path)
    path))

(defun my-advice-org-attach-expand-links (fn &rest args)
  "Make the advice of `org-attach-expand' conditional only when running `org-attach-expand-links'."
  (advice-add 'org-attach-expand :filter-return #'my-advice-org-attach-expand)
  (apply fn args)
  (advice-remove 'org-attach-expand #'my-advice-org-attach-expand))
(advice-add 'org-attach-expand-links :around #'my-advice-org-attach-expand-links)
```